# Iterating through JSON with Redux (how do I organise my reducers for this?)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

I have a JSON object which I want to load object by object. That is, the user clicks a button, then the object with id no. 1 will be displayed to him, if the user clicks the button again, the object with id no. 2 will be displayed - and so on. For now, I have made a reducer which simply returns the (whole) JSON, like so:

```
export default function() {
  return [
    {
      id: 1,
      attribute: "some values"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      attribute: "some other values"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      attribute: "some more values"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to now write a function which fetches always the next object from this JSON and display its results in my React application. I am not sure how to do this in Redux though. Would I have to keep track of the id? If so, how and where?

I was thinking of having a reducer entitled something like activeObject-reducer, which always contains the current object and all its attributes. I do not know however, how to pass an object from my JSON-reducer to this other reducer - is this the right way to do it in principle, or would you recommend some other, maybe completely different way?

Comment: When you reach the last item in the list, do you want it to cycle back to the beginning and return the first element again? Or once it reaches the end, the application stops displaying data?

Comment: It is more to understand how to make redux work in general, so either way would be interesting to me, but for the sake of keeping things simple and clear here, lets say yes, once its reached the end, that should be it!

Comment: You need to track the index and not id. Rewrite the reducer to return an object with 2 properties - one would be this array and the other would be the selectedIndex which you update as you keep clicking - the selectedIndex would be 0 or -1 initially - depending on your requirement

Comment: Do you want to fetch the next item from an API and build up the list, or you have the entire list in state and you simply want to walk through the selected index?

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely at least a few ways you could do this.

I would probably just expand your state key from an array to an object:

```
{
  active: {}
  all: []
}
```

Now you can re-use your existing reducer for `all` and add behavior for `active`:

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_LIST: // whatever action is currently updating your list
      const nextAll = originalListReducer(state.all, action);
      return { 
        active: nextAll[0], 
        all: nextAll
      };
    case NEXT_ACTIVE_ITEM:
      const {active, all} = state;
      const activeIndex = all.indexOf(active);
      const nextIndex = (activeIndex + 1) % all.length;
      return {
        ...state, 
        active: all[nextIndex] 
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

You could also make the `active` state managed by its own reducer you call through to, similar to the `originalListReducer` above, and [share the `all` state by passing it as an additional argument](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers). Something like:

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_LIST: // whatever action is currently updating your list
      const {all, active} = state;
      const nextAll = originalListReducer(all, action);
      const nextActive = nextActiveReducer(active, action, nextAll)
      return {
        all: nextAll,
        active: nextActive
      };
    case NEXT_ACTIVE_ITEM:
      const {all, active} = state;
      return {
        ...state,
        active: nextActiveReducer(active, action, all)
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const nextActiveReducer = (active, action, all) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_LIST:
      return all[0];
    case NEXT_ACTIVE_ITEM:
      return (all.indexOf(active) + 1) % all.length;
    default:
      return active;
  }
};
```

Another way you can do this is push the logic into your action creators. In this case you can use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to look at the current state and dispatch the appropriate "next" active object action:

```
const nextActiveObject = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {active, all} = getState();
    const activeIndex = all.indexOf(active);
    const nextIndex = (activeIndex + 1) % all.length;
    const nextActive = all[nextIndex];
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_ACTIVE, active: nextActive });
  }
};
```

Now your reducers become "dumb" updaters of `active` and `all` like this:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducer({
  all: allReducer,
  active: activeReducer
});

const allReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_LIST:
      return action.list;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const activeReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_ACTIVE:
      return action.nextActive;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Which way you want to go is [really up to you](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-business-logic).